# Execute multiple functions on program load - C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, loading, startup, launch

I'm trying to get my WPF application to run several functions/methods on program launch. I'd like to accomplish this with no user input (ie, user must first click a button, etc).

Where do I place the code that calls these functions, on program launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call them in your program's `Main` function, or in the constructor of the first window you create.

You might consider running them in another thread like this, if the data isn't needed immediately.

```
await Task.Run(() => 
{
    InitFunction1("arguments");
    InitFunction2("arguments");
});
```

Or using other task/async tools for loading them in parallel, or in an otherwise non-blocking fashion.

Using the [WPF Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application) as a reference point. You might put it in the main window constructor, or otherwise override and create your own version of the InitializeComponent method.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    YourCustomInitializationFunction();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

In order to run the initialization method asynchronously, move it to an async Loaded event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += async (s, e) => await YourCustomInitializationFunction();
}
```